# Flask: render js embedded webpage from a non-standard location

Tags: flask

My flask app has the following structure:

```
app.py
- templates/ 
- static/
- external/
```

Under `external`, I have a js embedded html file. It has the following structure:

```
external - 
     external.html
     js/
     img/
```

When I get a URL that looks like `http://<server:port>/external?key1=val2&key2=val2`, I want to send `external.html` to the client. My code looks like:

```
@app.route("/external")
    return flask.send_from_directory(external, 'external.html')
```

However, I am getting server exceptions and nothing is being returned back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a path issue. You may want to set the path to the folder manually

```
app = Flask(__name__, external_folder='external')  

@app.route('/external',methods=['GET'])  
def send_file(filename): 
    return send_from_directory(app.external_folder, filename)
```

Also, if this is in production, you should use a standard web server like Apache to serve your files

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed.